# send flutter firebase cloud messaging when app is completely shut down

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following the FCM from https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging
and if I am in app or I press home button and do not close app completely , the messages will be sent and every thing is good , but if I close the app completely , the messages will not be send .

what do I should doing ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of FCM messages:

- Notification messages
- Data messages

Nofitification messages can be handled when app is terminated, but you have to add `backgroundMessageHandler` and also register a plugin. Follow [guide on plugin docs](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#optionally-handle-background-messages) to do this properly.

Data messages, when app is terminated and on Android are unfortunately not handled by the plugin and the message is lost. On iOS messages are stored and delivered when app comes back to foreground. [The source](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages).

Comment: You mean if I add '''myBackgroundMessageHandler''', I can send message when app is shutdown?

Comment: Sorry I might have missed the point. Do you want to send notification from your app (like at the end of docs with http.post method)?

Comment: No,  I want have sth like onResume functionality when app is completely shutdown. Also I am using Kotlin in my project.