# Flutter push notification when app is closed

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, pushy

I want to have a push notification when the app is closed but I don't know how to do it.

I already tried firebase cloud messaging, it worked but the notification took around 3 to 5 min to come, but I need it instantly. I tried pushy.me, it works very well when the app is openned or in background but not when it's closed. And I didn't find anything in their documentation talking about closed apps. Maybe I can do something with flutter local notification and an API?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230998/send-flutter-firebase-cloud-messaging-when-app-is-completely-shut-down.

Comment: Try it out : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: no but I can't use FCM since it has a delay until the notification comes.

Answer (score 8):

This problem happens for me when the app is built in debug mode

When I build the app in release mode, I don't have this issue

Comment: this is the real solution

Comment: it work for me too release or profile mode, thz!

Answer (score 0):

It can caused by sometimes flutter version upgrade. In my case i tried to update my firebase_messaging to `latest version` and i followed this [ref](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9446#issuecomment-1240554285)